# Elements aren't displaying correctly using VW

Tags: css

[image: example of problem]I'm trying to position elements in a way so that when the browser width is changed, the webpage will scale everything in proportion, but what happens is that they shift a little. I don't understand why. I can adjust this okay using media queries, but they change drastically in mobile browsers. To illustrate what I'm talking about, I created an example in which I'm trying to keep this black text centered inside this green box. From my example, you'll see that scaling the browser on a desktop will keep the text in the box centered pretty well, but when switching to a mobile browser, the text will go out of the box. What can I do to keep it scaling correctly?

I realize that I can just fill the text div with a green background, but you have to understand that this is just an example of what I'm trying to do. The real webpage is much more sophisticated, so that will not be an option. I need to make sure that these divs scale appropriately. Thank you.

I provided an image to show the problem that I'm getting in my phone browser. It's a bit small, but you can see how the black text dips below the green box.

The example website: http://www.marifysworld.com

CSS:

```
@viewport {
  width: device-width;
  zoom: 1.0}

@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width}

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #fffff}

img {
display: block;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px}

.text {
font-size: 2.25vw;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
text-size-adjust: 90%}

.box {
width: 23.75%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 25%;
top: 40vw}

.divtext {
width: 20%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 26.75%;
top: 42.5vw}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="box" src="http://www.marifysworld.com/images/platform/box.jpg" />

<div class="divtext text">
Why won't this div of text stay in the center of the block in mobile browsers?
</div>
```

Comment: let us know what is an issue and what should be solved in specific. thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be clearer about the issue, or how to be more specific, but thanks.

Comment: The text is centered inside the green box already to me, so I don't understand what you mean by 'center'.

Comment: Did you look at it on a mobile browser? That's where I'm having the trouble.

Comment: Why do you have `left` on `box` and `text`?

Comment: You mean box and divtext? It's because I want the text to be positioned in that area. Is there another way to put it there that would avoid the text moving outside the box in a mobile browser?

Comment: Could you say which browsers you are using on what operating systems? And which give the desired result and which don’t?

Comment: The desktop Windows versions of Chrome, Edge, and Firefox are okay, but the mobile Android version of Chrome is not, nor is the Dolphin browser or the Samsung browser.

Answer (score 0):

Update: initially I thought the problem might be the (not universally supported) text-size-adjust property, but it seems this is unlikely. I leave those thoughts below just in case they are useful to someone else using that property.

Having been unable to reproduce the problem myself but seeing the useful image now put into the question I think we have to look at the actual font and how it is sized and using space. There are quite a few factors which maybe the browsers are setting different defaults for. Here's a few, there may well be more:

- font-family - most obvious but is whichever browser is causing the problem using the same default font as browsers not causing the problem? Try setting a specific font and see what happens
- Different fonts will take different widths for different characters. Try a monospace font - that will probably overflow - just to demonstrate the issue
- kerning - no I don't fully understand how different fonts use it and what they mean by 'normal' (which is probably the browser's default) but that will also alter the space used as will...
- ..line height - perhaps that needs to be specifically set
- font-weight will alter the space used - do all browsers/systems interpret say 400 exactly the same way
- I guess there's loads more that may differ between browsers - for example how exactly do they calculate the spacing needed to center text, will they always break a line at the same place etc.

Sorry this is a waffle, but there are so many factors that could make the text overflow and I don't understand them all in enough depth.

Basically what you need is to be able to scale the text div to force it to fit - for that you would need a bit of JS I think (?or is there an equivalent of contain for divs?)

ORIGINAL STUFF:
I am seeing text stay within the green box on a mobile device (IOS Safari) so I imagine the problem you are having is with another mobile device/browser such as Android.

If this is case the area to look at is the use of the CSS property
`text-size-adjust: 90%`

There are a couple of things to note here:

- According to MDN

> This is an experimental technology. Check ... carefully before using in production.

- This property is intended to be used in the case where a website has not been designed with smaller devices/viewports in mind.
- According to MDN, while Chrome on Android implements text-size-adjust fully, Firefox on Android and Safari on IOS do not support the percentage version.

I may be missing something but the question explicitly states that 'the webpage will scale everything in proportion'. Apart from possible inbuilt browser margin and padding on the div, everything is expressed as vw or % so I cannot see anything else that would have an adverse affect on the text positioning.

I also cannot see why this property is being used. It may or may not be causing the problem, but it certainly may affect how text is displayed on some browsers and it seems to be, at best, redundant for a site that is designed with proportionality in mind from the start.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.

I had another problem earlier in which my text was showing up bigger in certain mobile browsers than others, and I saw the text-size-adjustment solution which fixed it. If I don't use that, then the text is going to show up much bigger in those browsers, which will ruin the layout of the page. Is there another way to solve that issue?

In any case, even without that property, I still have the same issue of the text being outside the box in mobile browsers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, are you saying that the font-size being set by vw units is not correct on some browsers?

Comment: Correct. For instance, it works fine for the most part in Chrome on Windows, but the text moves down outside of the box on Chrome on Android. I can't understand it.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification, so if I look again without the text-size-adjustment I should still see the problem and it looks as if it's related to setting font-size with vw. Time to charge up the Android device. IOS seems OK.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the Safari browser. I didn't get a chance to test that yet, so at least I know it works on that.

Comment: Well, it's OK for me on Android too - but it's on a tablet not a narrow phone so has space and maybe therefore won't show the problem. Actually, I don't think I understand the problem properly now! Perhaps a screenshot or two in  your question would help us understand?

Comment: Good idea. It's a bit small, but you can see how the text dips below the box. I just added a screenshot of the problem to my original post.

Comment: Thanks, That helped, I'm clearer (I think!). I suspect the simple fact is that the font (plus its spacing) is too big. I'm being told by SO that this discussion is getting too long so I'll put thoughts into the answer as an update (not sure whether they are the answer or not though as I cannot reproduce the problem on any of my devices).

Comment: Thank you for your input. The ideas that you bring forth certainly can be a factor in the problem, but the problem with changing them is that they will also change how they look in the browsers in which they already look good in. So if I change them, they might look good in the mobile browser, but then look bad in the desktop browsers. But I'll keep looking into it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I reckon you need to leave things as they are and then apply a scale if necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using positions for your design but it is confusing and not possible.
Here is an idea to make this design work.
Just try it...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="divtext text">
       Why won't this div of text stay in the center of the block in mobile browsers?
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@viewport {
  width: device-width;
  zoom: 1.0}

@-ms-viewport {
  width: device-width}

body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #fffff;
}
.box{
  background: url('http://www.marifysworld.com/images/platform/box.jpg');
  width: 23.75%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
}
.divtext {
width: 90%;
  padding: 5% 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.text {
font-size: 2.25vw;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but this won't work for the final design. This current webpage is just an example to demonstrate what my problem is. I do have a question though. Why is using positioning not possible? Is there another way to position elements without using positioning properties? I'm confused.

Comment: I see that you're using the margin properties instead of the position properties, so I think that answers my second question. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. But if you want to work with positions than put that image inside a div container and than position it. it will work perfectly and you do not need to change much. Hope it will help you.